# iOS app what happens when a running app is upgraded

Tags: ios

When an app is running, and it is upgraded (via test flight upgrade or normal upgrade from app store), is the old version of the app still running until it's restarted?

Reason I ask is, that one of my testers was seeing behavior from a previous build.  This behavior was not seen from 2 other testers with the new builds on their devices.  But that one tester never killed the app after the upgrade.
After she killed the app and restarted it, the behavior was gone.

Hence this question.

Thanks in advance,
Anthony

Answer (score 1):

The app cannot be upgraded if it is in foreground. When a new upgrade is coming, and the app is not running (or in background mode), iOS terminates the app and updates it (you probably have seen icon animation of it, and you can't lunch the app during updating). After update you will have a fresh app without any bugs from previous version (but probably some new bugs as usually :D )

Comment: Thanks for the info.